# Composer autoload-dev does not work

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

The file autoload_psr4.php not contains the namespace from "autoload-dev" section only from "autoload" section.

When my composer.json reads

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Namespace\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "prs-4": {
        "Namespace\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
}
```

And I run

```
composer require vendor/namespace 1.0-dev
```

My /vendor/composer/autoload_prs4.php file appears as

```
// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Namespace\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),
);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What about checking for any typos like ` prs-4` ?

Answer (score 11):

My guess is that you're showing the `composer.json` of `vendor/namespace` package. If that's the case:

Take a look at [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev). It says: "autoload-dev (**root only**)". root only means it only applies to the root package. As you included the package, the shown `composer.json` file is not the root package and the `autoload-dev` section is thus ignored.

Comment: change directory to  package directory under 'vendor/',  and run phpunit

Answer (score 10):

Since this is the first Search Engine result when searching for "autoload-dev not working": In composer.json, if `"autoload-dev"` was added after defining and using `"autoload"`, run `$ composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Thanks man, saved me a headache I was wondering what that command did should of just ran it. I didn't wanna have to make my own autoloader and bootstrap that into the phpunit.xml